# Journey Builder -Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a journey on the basis of the Opportunity Stage. I am using a Decision Split flow control in the Jorurney. For Example the Contact enters the journey if the Opportunity Stage changes to "No Decision"

**I defined 2 paths in decision split:**

1. if Stage changes after creating time it should Exit the journey.
2. or else Remainder Path-- send another email to contact.

But the Journey Contact always goes to the Remainder path even if the stage has changed.

[image: Screenshot of decision split]

Comment: I updated my answer to include information on new features (from August '17 release) that should fix your problem. If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Event Data as opposed to Contact Data.

Evaluating against event data preserve the state of the contact when it enterered the journy, while Contact Data checks for changes in attributes.

Changing this should sort it out.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/

Comment: I would reverse the decision split. So stage name = "No Decision", as those are the ones you want to keep working with. The event data explanation could be the reason for what you are experiencing though.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, when journey event data enters into the journey, it becomes static ( you can check the entry source data extension to see that record),  The solution is to use Contact Data ( you need to map it in Contact Builder)

Comment: @BoHu if a field is mapped to the subscriberkey within the data extension, does it need an Attribute Group connection?  Or does this serve as an alternative to creating an attribute group for a data extension that is upserted in an automation?

Comment: @TomCallahan SubscriberKey is the PK to identify a subscriber in email studio, it doesn't have direct relationship to Contacts. You only need to map a data extension by linking a field (in most the case: subscriberkey field) in Data Extension to Contact Key in Contact Builder attribute group, if you need that data extension in Journey Builder. So when Journey builder is running, it can lookup the field value from that data extension by subkey/contactkey mapping relationship.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT *(after August '17 release)*:**

The problem that caused your problem has been fixed now as you can add the opportunity-id from contact-data to be compared with the opportunity to check in the path expression (using the *New Expression Builder* and the *"Add an attribute to compare"*-feature).

The new Expression Builder has the following added functionality that should help solve your problem:

> - Clearly compare two attributes in one argument
> - See path to each attribute in your Contact model
>   (Source: [August '17 Release Notes - Journey Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/journey_builder/))

For an explanation of the original problem see my original answer below.

**Related info:**

- [Blogpost on August '17 release features (including the **New Expression Builder** that fixes your problem)](https://markus.codes/2017/09/03/salesforce-marketing-cloud-august-17-release)
- [August '17 Release Notes - Journey Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/journey_builder/)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

**Problem:** As there is a one-to-many relationship between contacts and opportunities I guess this could be due to wrong decision split evaluation (path selection bug) in Marketing Cloud which will possibly be fixed end of 2017.

**Workaround:** Currently the best workaround is creating a custom split activity that checks the opportunity stage directly via the Sales/Service Cloud API. The only downsides are that you need to host the split and api calls are used for this. An additional upside of this workaround is, that this evaluation isn't subject to the synchronization delay of Marketing Cloud Connect as data is directly retrieved via the Sales/Service Cloud API.

**Related information:**

- *Blog article:* [How to fix wrong Decision Split evaluation in SFMC](https://markus.codes/2017/07/06/how-to-fix-wrong-decision-split-evaluation-in-sfmc)
- *Code example:* [Service Cloud Custom Split Activity for Journey Builder](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)
- *Success Article:* [Activities in Journey Builder, such as entry and exits events or decision splits, do not return expected results](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f6KZQAY&title=query-engine-needs-to-accept-pathing-information-in-filter)
- *StackExchange answer:* [Contact Data Decision Split for synchronized Salesforce DE leads to wrong path](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/172932/36218)