# SF Entry Data Event not working with decision split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Service Cloud is DOR. DOI Process in MC is triggered over the field Email_Optin=TRUE. I use an Salesforce Entry Event for my journey. After clicking the confirmation link the field Email_Optin_confirmed is updated to TRUE over an AMPScripted Cloud page. The field Email_Optin turns FALSE again. So far so good.

Now I want to use the information Email_Optin_confirmed=TRUE in a decision split (see Screen) but all user will be routed in to the Remainder Path. Why does this happen? Do I need to refresh something before decision split?

[image]
(Engagement Split is just here to split the users that did not open the DOI-Mail)

Thanks for your answers
Oliver

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is a bug in marketing cloud, which applies random path selection if there are multiple paths to an attribute, so some data read from service cloud cannot be mapped properly.

The other reason for this failing could could be, that synchronization didn't happen yet. Try using a longer wait, for example 30 minutes to make sure synchronization happened in the meantime.

**Documentation on the bug mentioned above:**

- [Contact Data Decision Split for synchronized Salesforce DE leads to wrong path](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/contact-data-decision-split-for-synchronized-salesforce-de-leads-to-wrong-path)
- [Activities in Journey Builder, such as entry and exits events or decision splits, do not return expected results](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f6KZQAY&title=query-engine-needs-to-accept-pathing-information-in-filter)
- [Possible Solution for bug: Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)

Comment: I thought that the synchronization happens in the Entry Event but so it did not. Is your suggestion to retrieve this update over data stream? I synchronize all this information in a Master DE. Shall I use the optin_confirmed from there?

Comment: The synchronization that happens in the entry event is just the data at the time of the event. Changes after that event aren't synchronized. If you want to query updated data you need to set up data streams to read that data from synchronized data extensions or the other option is retrieving it using a custom split activity, as this one you can find on my github account: [Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)