# Journey Builder - SF Event Campaign as Entry Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, campaign-member

We are trying to configure a Journey using SF campaign as Entry Event.The Campaign Members with Status "Approved" enter the Journey and a "Save The Date" email is sent.This is working fine but we need to send another email in the same journey based on if the Contact Accepts the "Save the date" email and the Contact Status becomes - "Accepted" in Salesforce Campaign.The status is updated in Salesforce using Eventforce depending on how the contact responds to emails.(so the status update is happening outside of Journey).

Post a wait period ,we have tried using Contact/Event data in Decision splits to check if CampaignMember.Status =Accepted and then send out "Invite" email.
This criteria does not work and it seems that Contact/Event data is not getting updated with the latest data from Sales cloud and hence criteria is failing and no "Invite" email is getting sent and contacts are following the alternate path where the contact exits the Journey.

Any thoughts how we can make this work.Have we missed anything while configuring journey?

Any of you faced such issue before and tried some workarounds?

Please Note: We are not using Sysnchronized DEs for getting campaign Data instead we are suing Salesforce Campaign Event where a campaign is selected and all the members of the campaign enter the Journey.(We donot have Synchronized DEs at all in MC system)

Regards,

Divyam

Answer (score 0):

This is most possibly due to a bug in the path selection and value retrieval algorithm.

Currently creating a custom split activity is the best option until the path selection feature is released. This feature is planned for the end of 2017, but this is no guaranteed release date.

**Further helpful information:**

- [How to fix wrong decision split evaluation in SFMC](https://markus.codes/2017/07/06/how-to-fix-wrong-decision-split-evaluation-in-sfmc)
- [Contact Data Decision Split for synchronized Salesforce DE leads to wrong path](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/172931/36218)
- [Code example for a Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)